# how to resolve an error with express.js with catching params in url

Tags: node.js, express, http

im trying to get que parameters in the url of my petition https, but i got this error in postman

```
Cannot DELETE /deleteEvent/
```

thats my code in node js with express, actually this works

```
app.delete('/deleteEvent',function(req,res){

  res.json({
    action: "se eliminara el evento con el numero"
  });
});
```

BUt this doesnt works

```
app.delete('/deleteEvent/:id',function(req,res){
  let id = req.params.id;
  res.json({
    action: "se eliminara el evento con el numero"+id
  });
});
```

how can i catch the params ?

Comment: What does your postman request look like?

Comment: status 404 not found

Comment: <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
 <pre>Cannot DELETE /deleteEvent/</pre>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Have you tried selecting the DELETE method from the dropdown in postman and enter a url similar to `http://localhost:3000/deleteEvent/1234` ?

Comment: yep, but i want to do my http petition like this "localhost:3000/deleteEvent/?id=1234"

Comment: Your original question is asking how to catch the params which your code is doing correctly.  I've added an answer that shows you how to access the query string values using the req.query property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `req.query.id` if you're going to capture the query string value instead.

```
app.delete('/deleteEvent', function (req, res) {
    let id = req.query.id;
    res.json({
        message: `Delete user: ${id}`
    })
})
```